# Como classificar um Triângulo

Tags: c++, matemática

Quero classificar um triângulo quanto aos lados, sendo que um triângulo com todos lados iguais é designado Equilátero, com todos os lados diferentes entre si é designado Escaleno e caso tenha apenas dois lados iguais entre si, designa-se Isósceles.

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
void HeaderClass::ClassificarUmTriangulo() {
int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, a, b, c;

cout << "Coordenadas do ponto1 (x): ";
cin >> x1;

cout << "Coordenadas do ponto1 (y): ";
cin >> y1;

cout << "Coordenadas do ponto2 (x): ";
cin >> x2;

cout << "Coordenadas do ponto2 (y): ";
cin >> y2;

cout << "Coordenadas do ponto3 (x): ";
cin >> x3;

cout << "Coordenadas do ponto3 (y): ";
cin >> y3;

Sleep(SLEEP_1);

a = sqrt(((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1)));
b = sqrt(((x3 - x2)*(x3 - x2)) + ((y3 - y2)*(y3 - y2)));
c = sqrt(((x1 - x3)*(x1 - x3)) + ((y1 - y3)*(y1 - y3)));

if (a == b && b == c) {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Triangulo equilatero." << endl;
}
```

Conseguindo pelo menos usar a condição `if` para obter um triângulo equilatro, mas ainda não consegui obter os restantes, qual será a maneira de, usando as condições `if`, `else if` e `else`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta fazer isto:

```
if (a == b && b == c) {
    cout << "Triangulo equilatero." << endl;
}
else if(a == b || b == c){
    cout << "Triangulo isosceles." << endl;
}
else
    cout << "Triangulo escaleno." << endl;
```

Consegue entender porquê?

Basicamente o algoritmo é o seguinte:

Se os três lados são iguais (a=b `e` b=c) então é equilátero, caso contrário se pelo menos um par é idêntico (a=b `ou inclusivo` b=c) então é isósceles, caso contrário é escaleno).

Comment: Mas, esse `else if(a == b || b == c)` não irá causar bugs ou algo do género ?

Comment: Não. Irei editar a questão.

Comment: Eu estava a pensar numa coisa mais complicada, e afinal era assim tão simples.. eu pensei uma coisa do género `else if( a == b && *a não é igual a c etc..)`

Comment: @André Creio que tens de dar uma olhada com mais calma à estrutura `if (condição_1) (...) else if (condição_2) (...) else (...)`.